# Cassandra performance issue

Tags: cassandra, datastax

We have a table that looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE arc_dynamic.transit_map (
    sal text,
    pfn text,
    transit_map_id text,
    create_program_id text,
    create_timestamp timestamp,
    cutoff_times map<text, text>,
    derived_priority int,
    effective_date text,
    modify_program_id text,
    modify_timestamp timestamp,
    relationship_type_id text,
    solr_query text,
    stop set<text>,
    transit_days map<text, int>,
    trigger_id text,
    PRIMARY KEY (sal, pfn, transit_map_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (pfn ASC, transit_map_id ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';

CREATE CUSTOM INDEX arc_dynamic_transit_map_create_timestamp_index ON arc_dynamic.transit_map (create_timestamp) USING 'com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex';
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX arc_dynamic_transit_map_derived_priority_index ON arc_dynamic.transit_map (derived_priority) USING 'com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex';
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX arc_dynamic_transit_map_modify_timestamp_index ON arc_dynamic.transit_map (modify_timestamp) USING 'com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex';
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX arc_dynamic_transit_map_relationship_type_id_index ON arc_dynamic.transit_map (relationship_type_id) USING 'com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex';
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX arc_dynamic_transit_map_solr_query_index ON arc_dynamic.transit_map (solr_query) USING 'com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex';
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX arc_dynamic_transit_map_trigger_id_index ON arc_dynamic.transit_map (trigger_id) USING 'com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex';
```

When I run:

```
select * from transit_map where sal='XXX_953';
```

It times out:

```
ReadTimeout: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' 
responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info=
{'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

If I limit it to 10 rows or less, it comes back. Anything more, times out. I'm trying to figure out where it's going wrong (either too many sstables, tombstones, something else), but I can't figure out how to get at this.

I've enabled tracing. For the 10 row limit or less it doesn't "look too bad" (at least it has some output).

When I put in 11 row limit, or leave it blank (no limit), no output comes back from the tracing.

Any help where to go is greatly appreciated. I'm coming from a long-time Oracle background, and am lost on how to figure this out in Cassandra.

Comment: How many rows are you expecting to get back with that query?

Answer (score 1):

Creating maps and other objects are heavy operations for Cassandra.
In case this maps are not constrained in size timeouts like this are quite common.

From personal experience map sizes shouldn't be over a couple of dozen or so.

Try and model your data in a way maps are very constrained in size or even better you don't use them at all. one solution can be changing `transit_days` to `uuid` type and having a connection table that looks something like this:

`CREATE TABLE arc_dynamic.transit_map_days_per (
    transit_day_id uuid,
    data text
    PRIMARY KEY (transit_day_id)
)`

you would then be able to get the "map" from this table as a list of tuples and manipulate it on your end

Comment: raam86,I really appreciate you taking the time to offer your advice on this. As I am learning by fire, my next question would be: How would one know that is indeed the problem? Where would I look? As trace doesn't output anything, I don't even know where else I would have to look. I tried to increase my client timeout by setting client_timeout value in my cqlshrc file, but it didn't help. My guess that's for connecting, not querying, but not sure. Even if it did work, and I received rows back, would there be any clues that the map was the problem?

Comment: Easiest will be to remove the offending map and see what happens. You can always thread dump. JVM dump and search for Cassandra benchmark, they have some tools for stats which I don't currently remember and also http://aryanet.com/blog/cassandra-garbage-collector-tuning

Comment: raam86, thanks for the heads up on this. What I found out from some others on the team is that they never have more than 14 items in the map, and that the problem was actually a bug with the datastax release we're on and that compaction and repair fixes the issue. I do appreciate your response though and will play around more with it. Learning more each day...

Comment: What version are you using? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sure. Here is what was sent to me via e-mail: "XXXXX ran the compaction last night on the transit_map keyspace and it resolved the issue.  This is the bug in DSE 4.72 that is resolved in 4.8.X." Not sure the bug number. Can get it, if you're interested.

Comment: Sure, it sounds interesting, thank you for your efforts.